# Why the code works on debuggin mode but not works on release mode on İntellij

Tags: java, sorting, intellij-idea, arraylist

I am making an experiment about algorithms efficiency, so I use different size of integer data like 512,1024,2048,..,131072,251281 when I run the code below

```
 for (int i=0; i<experiment.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("experiment number : "+i);

            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {

                ArrayList<Integer> exp_array = new ArrayList<>();



                if(i==9){

                    exp_array.addAll(array.subList(0, experiment[i]));
                }else {
                    exp_array.addAll(array.subList(0, experiment[i]+1));
                }

                long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                insertionSort.sort(exp_array);
                long elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
                resultsInsertion1.add(elapsedTime);


                if(j==9){
                    sortedArrays.add(exp_array);
                }

            }
            averageResultsInsertion1.add(avarage.findAverage(resultsInsertion1));
            resultsInsertion1.clear();
        }




        System.out.println(averageResultsInsertion1);


        // insertion2


        ArrayList<Long> resultsInsertion2 = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Long> averageResultsInsertion2 = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i=0; i<experiment.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("experiment number : "+i);

            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {



                long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                insertionSort.sort(sortedArrays.get(i));
                long elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
                resultsInsertion2.add(elapsedTime);



            }
            averageResultsInsertion2.add(avarage.findAverage(resultsInsertion2));
            resultsInsertion2.clear();
        }

        System.out.println("insertion 2 : "+averageResultsInsertion2);
```

The averaResultsInsertion2 gives me array filled with zeros but when I run the code on debugging mode it works how can I fix this problem ?

PC: MacBook Air 2017
IDE: Intellij 2022

Comment: I recommend that you post a [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ResultsInsertion2 is filled with elapsed time in milliseconds, so if your sorting is executed under an millisecond you will get .. zeros

ps : please format your code next time

Comment: thank you for your answers this was my first question on StackOverflow so that's why I asked too long I will be more careful next time